# Let the $.post function return the response in the parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got this code:

```
function server_request(module,section,action,data) {
    data['module'] = module;
    data['section'] = section;
    data['action'] = action;
    var responsetxt = null;
    $.post('../application/server.php', data, function(data) {
        responsetxt = data;
    });
    return responsetxt;
}
```

And it return's `null` ?

What i want is let the `server_request` function return the responseText?
But at some way it doesn't work, why? And how to let it work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req

Comment: This question gets asked *all the time*.  It appears to be a fundamental stumbling block in learning how asynchronous Javascript works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're providing a callback function to $.post, which will be run when the request is returned. The server_request function returns immediately (i.e. before the response is available) so responsetxt will still be null.

To get around this you could add a callback parameter to server_request, then execute it in the anonymous function you provide to the $.post call:

```
function server_request(module,section,action,data,callback) {
    data['module'] = module;
    data['section'] = section;
    data['action'] = action;
    $.post('../application/server.php', data, function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

You could then use this like:

```
$(function() {
    var module = x, section = y, data = z;
    server_request(module, section, data, function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response); // do stuff with your response
    });
});
```

Check out continuation passing style for more information ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style and http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/).

Comment: Nah, I don't want functions etc. outside the `server_request` function, I realy need to let the `server_request` function return the response, but how...

Comment: or even `$.post('../application/server.php', data, callback)`

Comment: ROFL, you beat me, I was posting while you posted this, sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @Stijntjhe: You're going to have to use functions, that's the name of the game nowadays in javascript, especially with these post/ajax/html type calls.

Comment: Stijntjhe: you could make the request blocking by specifying 'async: false' but that's not recommended as it'll lock up the browser. Beyond this it isn't really possible to return the result from that function - it's just something you have to deal with when using AJAX.

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was a duplicate. +1 for this one.

Comment: The `$.post()` function returns an `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseText` set? :D
But when I call that variable like `console.log($.post(blabla).responseText);` it logs nothing, weird.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the return value, but only when doing a synchronous call instead of an asynchronous one:

```
function server_request(module,section,action,data,callback) {
    data['module'] = module;
    data['section'] = section;
    data['action'] = action;
    responsetxt = $.ajax({
       "url": '../application/server.php', 
       "async": false,
       "type": "POST",
       "data": data
       }).responseText;
    return responsetxt;

}
```

Remember that a synchronous call like this freezes the browser until the server responds.